# How to install SAPRFC with PHP 5.4.4 in Windows 32 system?

Tags: php, saprfc

I've tried a lot of things given over the internet to setup SAPRFC in Windows but they all are talking about PHP 5.2 version but everyone knows that we are using PHP 5.x nowadays.

I'm running Xampp server where my PHP version is 5.4.4 and I need to communicate with SAP server through PHP script. I've tried the procedure of copying `librfc.dll` in `system32` folder and `php_saprfc.dll` in `php/ext` folder and also modification of `php.ini` but it doesn't help me.

I have followed these steps:

**Installation:**

1. Extract zip file `saprfc-$VERSION$-$PHP_VERSION$.zip`
2. Copy `php-saprfc.dll` to your extensions directory (e.g. `C:\PHP\extensions`)
3. Edit `php.ini` file (in Windows system directory, e.g. `C:\WINNT, C:\WINDOWS`) and add line: `extension=php_saprfc.dll`
4. Copy `librfc32.dll` (from SAPGUI install CD) to the Windows system directory or simple install SAPGUI on your machine.

**Compilation:**

1. Extract php sources to `C:\PHP-x.y.z`
2. Extract php win support files to `C:\PHP-x.y.z\win32`
3. Install RFCSDK to `C:\PHP-x.y.z\rfcsdk`
4. Copy SAPRFC sources to `C:\PHP-x.y.z\ext\saprfc`
5. Copy `php4ts.lib` or `php5ts.lib` (from PHP binaries) to `C:\PHP-x.y.z\win32`
6. For PHP5 copy `saprfc.dsp5` to `saprfc.dsp`
7. Open project `C:\PHP-x.y.z\ext\saprfc\saprfc.dsp` in Microsoft Visual C++ 6.
8. Under Tools|Option|Directory set path for Include files and for Library files:

   ```
     (C:\PHP-x.y.z\win32\include; C:\PHP-x.y.z\rfcsdk\include;
      C:\PHP-x.y.z\win32\lib; C:\PHP-x.y.z\rfcsdk\lib)
   ```
9. Set active configuration to "saprfc - Windows_TS" (under Build menu)
10. Build `php_saprfc.dll`.
11. Compiled DLL you find in `C:\PHP-x.y.z\Release_TS directory`

But I'm not getting the compilation part.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version is from 2009 and can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saprfc/files/saprfc/1.4.1/). For newer PHP versions you have to compile the extension yourself (at least the docs say so). Seems like the devs didn't make the jump to the newer versions because of the compiler needed. In the compilation docs it still says Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0. AFAIK modern PHP uses 9.0. So you propably need to tinker a bit with it. Or you might ask in the SAP forums if someone did the necessary work already.

Comment: but what additional software should I install and what do you mean by manual compilation of dll file?

Comment: Have a look at the extensions web site. There you will find installation instructions. Within this file it is described how to compile a new php_saprfc.dll. If you're not familiar with C++ or don't have the necessary tools you might not be able to compile it.

Comment: actually I always worked with php but I've a C++ experienced person. what should I tell him?

Comment: I tried to build it (but not completed it), see my steps here: https://github.com/piersharding/php-sapnwrfc/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

You can download precompiled version here: 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/saprfcsapnwrfc/files/